# I have a Indian passport and am travelling to US with a stopover of 7 hours at Haneda. Do I need a transit visa?

Tags: visas, transit, indian-citizens, hnd

I am an indian citizen taking a flight from Singapore to US.
I have a layover of 6.5 hours at Haneda International Airport.
Do I need a transit visa. I do not plan to venture outside the Airport.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=on&PASSTYPES=PASS&NA=in&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&DE=00&AR=00&TR=jp&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&TR=00&user=FLIGHTWORX&subuser=FLIGHTWORX), the database used by airlines:

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets for a max.
>   transit time of 72 hours through **Tokyo Haneda
>   (HND)** or Osaka Kansai (KIX).

So no, you do **not** need a visa.